# How to render same component with different props inside react-router <Route>?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a `News` component which takes some props, and I want to make it re-render whenever I click on `<Link />` with the corresponding category props. It updates the URL but does not re-render the component.

```
<Routes>
  <Route
    path="/"
    element={
      <News
        country={this.country}
        apiKey={this.API_KEY}
        pageSize={this.pageSize}
        category="general"
      />
    }
  />
  <Route
    path="/business"
    element={
      <News
        country={this.country}
        apiKey={this.API_KEY}
        pageSize={this.pageSize}
        category="business"
      />
    }
  />
  <Route
    path="/entertainment"
    element={
      <News
        country={this.country}
        apiKey={this.API_KEY}
        pageSize={this.pageSize}
        category="business"
      />
    }
  />
</Routes>
```

These are my `<NavLink />`

```
<li className="nav-item">
  <NavLink className="nav-link" aria-current="page" to="/">
    Home
  </NavLink>
</li>
{this.props.categories.map((category) => {
  return (
    <li key={category} className="nav-item">
      <NavLink to={`/${category}`} className="nav-link">
        {category[0].toUpperCase() +
          category.slice(1, category.length)}
      </NavLink>
    </li>
  );
})}
```

Comment: Where is the `Link`?

Comment: @Aleksandar I have link on my `<Navbar />` Component and It works fine. It updates the URL as should be.

Comment: Had a similar issue in the past. Try giving each of the components a [`key`](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) attribute with different values.

Comment: If you [edit] the post to include a more complete [mcbve] that includes the `News` component we can see what the actual dependency is and provide more refined solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`react-router`/`react-router-dom` optimizes rendering by keeping the same component instance mounted *even though* it is rendered on multiple routes. This is a performance optimization to save unmounting and remounting the same component only to pass it different props values. In other words, the component remains mounted even though the route changed, and should handle the props value updating in the `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method or `useEffect` hook with dependency.

Based on the routes and the passed props it's really that this `News` component has *some* dependency on the `category` prop as that's the only prop I see that is different.

The `News` component should likely have a `useEffect` hook with a dependency on this `category` prop to run/load whatever data is different based on this different prop value.

Example:

```
const News = ({ apiKey, category, country, pageSize }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    // a dependency value changed, rerun some logic
  }, [apiKey, category, country, pageSize]);

  ...
};
```

If `News` is a React class-based component then it should implement the `componentDidUpdate` method.

```
class News extends React.Component {
  ...

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    const { apiKey, category, country, pageSize } = this.props;

    if (
      category !== prevProps.category
      /* || other props change conditions */ 
    ) {
      // a dependency value changed, rerun some logic
    }
  }

  ...
};
```

Also, based on this, since it also appears that the `category` and the URL path match, *for the most part*, you could likely also make the code more dry by rendering a single route with the category as a route path parameter, and applying the same `useEffect` hook logic to rerun the logic that depends on the category value.

Example:

```
<Routes>
  <Route
    path="/:category?"
    element={
      <News
        country={this.country}
        apiKey={this.API_KEY}
        pageSize={this.pageSize}
      />
    }
  />
</Routes>
```

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

const News = ({ apiKey, country, pageSize }) => {
  const { category = "general" } = useParams();

  useEffect(() => {
    // a dependency value changed, rerun some logic
  }, [apiKey, category, country, pageSize]);

  ...
};
```

Again, if `News` is a Class-component, then use the appropriate `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method and implement a custom [`withRouter` Higher Order Component](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/faq#what-happened-to-withrouter-i-need-it) in order to inject the `category` route path parameter as a prop.

Using a React key on the `News` component ***should only be used as a last resort*** since it invloves actually tearing down, e.g. unmounting, and remounting the component which is a lot more work than simply rerendering the component with updated prop values.

Comment: I'm using class based components, So I can not use `useEffect` hook, but thanks for the extra information about React key.

Comment: @JeetGangwar It's 2023, who is still writing or using Class components? You should convert to React function components so you can use React hooks, or create a [withRouter](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/faq#what-happened-to-withrouter-i-need-it) HOC so you can access the route params in a class component and implement the dependency logic I describe in my answer in the `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method.

Comment: I am a student and am currently learning React. I am just using class components for learning purpose. So I can also understand about class components.

Comment: @JeetGangwar I see. Well React class-components were effectively deprecated when React hooks were released several years ago. I've tweaked my answer to help/cover also class-component usage.

Answer (score 0):

We can simply add a unique `key` in the `element` component. It will `re-render` every time with some different `props`.

```
<Route
    path="/business"
    element={
      <News
        key="business" { /*A unique key */}
        country={this.country}
        apiKey={this.API_KEY}
        pageSize={this.pageSize}
        category="business"
      />
    }
  />
```